# Using Jsoup to scrape Youtube

Tags: java, web-scraping, youtube, jsoup, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get some data from Youtube videos that the Youtube Data API doesn't provide. (Music Metadata when you press Read More)

Jsoup seems to be the right library to gather this data. I try to get the Document Object by calling

```java
Jsoup.connect(videoUrl).get()
```

The problem now is that I always get the page where you get redirected to, to accept cookies.
I also tried adding the userAgent but it didn't work.

Does anybody know how to get past the cookie page with Jsoup?
Or maybe any other idea to gather the music metadata

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Click on the "accept" button for cookies with your web scraper (Selenium does it well)
2. Manually click on "accept" and then refresh the webpage while checking the `Network` tab of your web browser with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +<kbd>E</kbd>. Copy as cURL with and without having clicked on the "accept" button you will find the difference and what parameter to provide to your web scraper to express your consent and bypass this menu.